# keras embedding layer build

Tags: keras, time-series

I am taking sequence models class by Prof Andrew Ng. Here we are building embedding layer as below

```
 # Define Keras embedding layer with the correct output/input sizes, make it non-trainable. Use Embedding(...). Make sure to set trainable=False.


embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_len, emb_dim, trainable = False)


    # Build the embedding layer, it is required before setting the weights of the embedding layer. Do not modify the "None".
    embedding_layer.build((None,))
```

I am having difficulty in understanding build method. What exactly below function is adding. I am not able to find build API. References on this API will be helpful.

Build the embedding layer, it is required before setting the weights of the embedding layer. Do not modify the "None".

embedding_layer.build((None,))

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is no need to call `build()` yourself on a layer.

You only care for it when you write your on Layers as described [here](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).
There, `build` is one of the required methods. You use it to define the weights of your layer. When you call `model.compile()` on your final model, this will internally call each Layer's `build()` method and pass it the output shape of the previous layer.

So, the comment `it is required before setting the weights of the embedding layer` is actually correct: In order to set weights, the layer needs to know the proper shape which it will be told by calling `build()`. However, that doesn't mean you have to call `build()` yourself. You can also set the weights after the model is compiled.

So, in summary, unless your code is doing anything fancy (which I don't know because you didn't post anything further), this call to `build` is obsolete.